# How can I increase the performance of League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends, performance

In League of Legends, I can only manage 30 frames per second (or lower) on Low quality. Is that normal, or not?

How can I increase the performance?

I have a G41MT-S2PT motherboard, a PowerColor ATI Radeon HD 5450, and 4 GB of RAM.

Comment: i have the same problem...you CPU and RAM are the bottleneck

Answer (score 5):

The Radeon HD 5450 is a 5-year-old video card, and was a low-performance budget model even when it was new. Your poor performance is more than likely primarily due to that.

If your other PC components are similarly aged, however, replacing just the video card may not bring you as much of an improvement as you may want. [Here are League's system requirements, for your reference.](https://support.riotgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/201752654-Minimum-and-Recommended-System-Requirements)

Comment: Ok thanks very much for the info but can u tell me a good pc components set for a good price as my coutry sell this thing at high price to get my fps at max

Comment: @Ahmed You'll probably have better luck if you go to a place that's designed for that sort of thing, like [/r/BuildaPC on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/buildapc) or something similar.